# Transform function to generic function

Tags: c#, generics

I have the functions that inserts entities to database.  For example, one of them looks like:

```
public async void InsertInspections(ObservableCollection<Inspections> inspections)
{
    _connection.CreateTableAsync<Inspections>().Wait();

    foreach (var inspection in inspections)
    {
        var task = _connection.Table<Inspections>().
                   Where(v => v.InspectionId == inspection.InspectionId).ToListAsync();
         task.Wait();

         if (task.Result.Any()) 
             _connection.UpdateAsync(inspection);
         else
             _connection.InsertAsync(inspection);
     }
 }
```

I would like to transform it to generic function, but I am not sure whet is the best way to pass the lambda function in the `Where` method.

Something like:

```
public async void InsertEntities<T>(ObservableCollection<T> entities)
{
    _connection.CreateTableAsync<T>().Wait();

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var task = _connection.Table<T>().
                   // what is the best way to pass this function to the method ???
                   Where(v => v.InspectionId == entity.InspectionId).ToListAsync();
         task.Wait();

         if (task.Result.Any()) 
             _connection.UpdateAsync(entity);
         else
             _connection.InsertAsync(entity);
     }
 }
```

Should I use delegates, lambdas or create this function as method of Entity class ?

Comment: There's no point in using asynchronous methods if you're just going to synchronously wait on them.  Either use synchronous methods, or `await` the async methods.  You also have an `async `method with no `await` calls, and the method returns `void` when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
InsertEntities<T>(ObservableCollection<T> entities, Func<T, bool> exp)
.Where(exp)
```

Also, I would read the comment above. I don't think your asynchrony is set up quite right.